# Losing Session Value in Sitecore 9.0.2

Tags: azure, session-state, redis

I have a **Sitecore 9.0.2** portal in Azure PaaS from where we are making some transactions. I am posting form to the payment gateway using form post method and gateway is returning the response to a particular portal URL. Before posting the form to the payment gateway, I am storing some user details in **Http Session**. When the response comes from the payment gateway to the portal, I am reading the session value and updating the record in DB. The code was working for a long time however suddenly since last week the Http Session is giving me null value. In my portal **Azure Redis Cache** is configured as session provider.

Below is my `Session configuration`:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="redis" cookieless="false" timeout="20"
      sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">
      <providers> 
        <add name="redis" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Redis" applicationName="Application"
          connectionString="redis.sessions" pollingInterval="2" compression="true"/>
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Please help me how can I keep the user session while posting the form to payment gateway and reading the response.

Thanks.